# C++: creating an event repeatedly called by timer

Tags: c++, function, events, lambda, timer

I wanted to redo a Conway's Game of Life thing I did in Java, but this time use ncurses and C++. Obviously I need a timed event so I can run out the simulation at a rate which it can be viewed. Turns out it is a hell of a lot harder to make a timed event in C++ than it is in Java. I am not as experienced in C++ than I am in Java. I have already looked around online, and what I found led me to the code I have below. Upon executing it produces no result in the terminal. What exactly am I doing wrong?

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <chrono>
#include <future>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

class callBackTimer //no idea how this works, got it from Stack Overflow thread
{

public:
    callBackTimer()
    :_execute(false)
    {}

    void start(int interval, std::function<void(void)> func)
    {
        _execute = true;
        std::thread([=]()
                    {
                        while (_execute)
                        {
                            func();
                            std::this_thread::sleep_for(
                            std::chrono::milliseconds(interval));
                        }
                    }).detach();
    }

    void stop()
    {
        _execute = false;
    }

private:
    bool _execute;

};

void timerExec()
{
    cout << "SNAFU" << endl;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    callBackTimer timer; //declare the timer
    std::function<void(void)> exec = timerExec; //declare a pointer to timerExec
    timer.start(25, std::bind(exec)); //start the timer

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try some blocking I/O before returning from main, for example `getch()`.

Comment: @BenVoigt what do you mean, explain?

Comment: Since you are calling `detach()` on your thread, `main()` is not waiting for it and returns, destroying the thread immediately. Use `join()` to make `main()` wait for the thread to finish (and perhaps add a condition to break out of the `while` loop).

Comment: @cantordust could you explain how to do this? Sorry, I'm not too experienced with C++...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wait for the thread to finish what it is doing, which is usually accomplished by calling `join()`. So maybe something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <chrono>
#include <future>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

class callBackTimer //no idea how this works, got it from Stack Overflow thread
{

public:
    callBackTimer()
        :_execute(false)
    {}

    void setup(int interval, std::function<void(void)> func)
    {
        _execute = true;
        thread = std::thread([=]()
        {
//          while (_execute)
            for (int steps = 0; steps < 100; ++steps)
            {
                func();
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(interval));
            }
        });
    }

    void stop()
    {
        _execute = false;
    }

    void run()
    {
        thread.join();
    }

private:
    bool _execute;
    std::thread thread;

};

void timerExec()
{
    cout << "SNAFU" << endl;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    callBackTimer timer; //declare the timer
    std::function<void(void)> exec = timerExec; //declare a pointer to timerExec
    timer.setup(25, std::bind(exec)); //start the timer
    timer.run();

    return 0;
}
```

Calling `detach()` is OK, but you have to make `main()` wait for the thread manually. You also need a condition to break out of the `while` loop, otherwise it will go on forever. Hope that helps!

Comment: Glad I could help. You should also look at `std::condition_variable` for communication between threads.